# Insert text in specific cell in Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to insert text in 5th row ist column and another text in 5th row 2nd column... How do I do this? Below is the code am using and get out of range exception:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet3;
Excel.Range oRange;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet2.Name = "The chart sheet";

xlWorkSheet2.Cells[5, 1] = "First Name";
xlWorkSheet2.Cells[5,2] = "Last Name";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before the cell insertion above you have to add a worksheet

```
Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet wkSheetData = excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
excelApplication.Cells[5, 2] = "TextField";
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? I need more to go one here. So, you no longer get the `OutOfRangeException` and instead now get `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: i have added that row like wise Invoke((Action)(() => { dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1); }));as i needed a blank row in bw for formatting. i dont have any loop. am getting the result for other cells bt not for this added row cell.

Comment: Am actually exporting data from grid to excel

Comment: I am afraid I am finding it hard to understand this new problem. It might be worth asking another question. If my answer has solved your initial question accept it, then ask another question with further details regarding the new error including the code that you use to call the Excel export stuff...