# Insert data to specific cell in excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have been looking around checking how to insert/update data into an existing excel spreadsheet into a specific cell. I first came upon this thread :

[Insert text in specific cell in Excel c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954166/insert-text-in-specific-cell-in-excel-c-sharp)

Not sure if I read it right but I don't see anything with regards to using a certain excel file. Would I then be using a combination with this kind of code?

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-update.htm

Sorry if I'm just using links, don't want to clutter this thread with so much code.

Answer (score 2):

I have not gone through the link that you have mentioned in the post. However, if you are looking at writing or updating the value in a particular cell, you can do it using this line of code:

```
workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = cellValue;
```

`rowIndex` and `columnIndex` are the integer values that represent the index of the row and column of the cell in which you are trying to write/update. `cellValue` is the value you are trying to write in the cell. This should be a string.

Sample code:

```
//Create an excel application object
Excel.Application excelAppObj = new Excel.Application();
excelAppObj.DisplayAlerts = false;

//Open the excel work book
Excel.Workbook workBook = excelAppObj.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, false, false);

//Get the first sheet of the selected work book
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//Write 20 in Cell - C3
workSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "20";

//Save work book (.xlsx format)
workBook.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, null, null, false,
false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, null, null, null);

//Release resources
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
worksheet.Cells[rownumber,columnnumber]="value";
```

Answer (score 1):

On the site that you named, there's another link on there called [How to insert data to Excel using OLEDB](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-insert.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The code in the first link is using `Interop` to update an Excel file and the second link is using `OleDb`. You shouldn't really mix the two.

The code from the first one should be easy enough to adjust, you can load a specific excel file by using the `Workbooks.Open()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx). Changing the line

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
```

to

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(yourFilename);
```

Where `yourFileName` is a string that contains the full path to the Excel file you wish to open should work for you.