# How to write data in an excel file at particular cell using c#

Tags: c#

Below is the code I'm using I'm calling Driver method and passing the respective parameters row coloumn etc after executing the code runs successfully but nothing is written on excel file , is it possible to send directly the cell number like b5 etc if yes what modifications should I make:

```
namespace PEPI_Performance.Utility
{
/// <summary>
/// Description of ExcelWriter.
/// </summary>

public class ExcelWriter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance.
    /// </summary>
    public ExcelWriter()
    {
        // Do not delete - a parameterless constructor is required!
    }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook exlWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet exlWS;
    object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


    public void Driver(int row , int col, string time, int runNumber){
        //GlobalLib.clsExcel objExcel = new GlobalLib.clsExcel();
        //  Report.Info(ApplicationName);
        string sDataFile = "Ranorex_Reports.xls";
        //ClsExcel objExcel = new ClsExcel();
        //ArrayList colTF = null;
        //  int rowCount = 0;
        string sFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(sDataFile);
        Report.Success(sFilePath);

        string sOldvalue = "Vopak_Automation\\bin\\Debug\\" + sDataFile;
         sFilePath=sFilePath.Replace(sOldvalue,"")+
        "PEPI_Performance\\ExecutionReport\\"+ sDataFile;
        fnOpenExcel(sFilePath,runNumber);

        //colTF = objExcel.fnGetTestFlow();
        writeExcel(row,col,time);
        fnCloseExcel();
    }



    //Open Excel file
    public int fnOpenExcel(string sPath
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.OptionalAttribute,
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute(0)]  // ERROR:
    Optional parameters aren't supported in C#
                           int iSheet){

        int functionReturnValue = 0;
        try {

            exlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            exlApp.Visible = true ;
            //exlWB = exlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath);
            exlWB =
 exlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
            exlWS =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)exlWB.Worksheets[iSheet];
            //((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)exlWS).Activate();
            //((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)exlWS).Cells() = 2;




            functionReturnValue = 0;
            Report.Info(functionReturnValue.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            functionReturnValue = -1;
            Report.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }


    // Close the excel file and release objects.
    public int fnCloseExcel(){
        //exlWB.Close();

        try{
            exlApp.Quit();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exlWS);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exlWB);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exlApp);

            GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Report.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        Report.Info("closed");
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeExcel(int i, int j , string time){
        Excel.Range exlRange = null;
        exlRange = (Excel.Range)exlWS.UsedRange;
        //exlRange.Select();
        Report.Info("hi");
        //(Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[i, j]).Value2 != null;
        //(Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[i , j].
        ((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells["B5",Type.Missing]).Formula = time;
            //((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[i, j]).Value2 = time;
    }

   }
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because you need to add a worksheet... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954166/insert-text-in-specific-cell-in-excel-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to refer the cells

either you can use the row and cell with integer or by cell reference

below is the example

### By CELL reference

```
public void writeExcel(int i, int j , string time){
        Excel.Range exlRange = null;
        exlRange = (Excel.Range)exlWS.UsedRange;
        //exlRange.Select();
        Report.Info("hi");

       // ((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells["B5",Type.Missing]).Formula = time;
       //((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[i, j]).Value2 = time;

        exlWS.Range["B5"].Formula = time;


    }
```

### By row and cell as integer

```
public void writeExcel(int i, int j , string time){
        Excel.Range exlRange = null;
        exlRange = (Excel.Range)exlWS.UsedRange;
        //exlRange.Select();
        Report.Info("hi");

       // ((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells["B5",Type.Missing]).Formula = time;
       //((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[i, j]).Value2 = time;

       ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[2, 2]).Formula = time;


    }
```